# Robot framework: running test cases in batch makes them fail, while running a single test case works

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have 22 Robot framework test cases in a folder. All the test cases work perfectly if run individually.
If I try to run them all together, with the command `robot .` (from the TestCases directory) most of them fail.

The ones that fail make use of a python script to get the performance log of the webpage, with the following code:

`d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}`

the error I get is:

> InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found

the strange thing is that this happens only when I run all test cases together. Otherwise, error does not appear and log is retrieved correctly.

How can I fix this so the test cases work also when run in batch?

This is the file structure:
[image: file structure]

Each ROBOT file contains only 1 test case. In the driver.py the custom keywords are defined and called at the beginning of each TC with:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library           driver.py

*** Variables ***


*** Keywords ***
   Get Logs2
        [Arguments]     ${arg1}
   Get Chrome Browser Logging Capability
   Find String
```

the code that throws the error is in the file "driver.py":

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


def get_chrome_browser_logging_capability():
    d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
    d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
    return d


def get_logs2(driver):
    f = open("demofile2.txt", "w")
    a = driver.get_log('performance')
    for entry in a:
        f.write(str(entry))
        f.write('\n')
    f.close()




def find_string(mystring):
    f = open("demofile2.txt", "r")
    for x in f:
        for element in mystring:
            if element in x:
                print("found")
                return True
    f.close()
```

Comment: It looks more like, one reason it works during the individual run and fails in the batch may be due to the use of relative paths in the test case. Maybe try using absolute paths in the code.  Not Sure, as told by @BenceKaulics it's good to share the code and folder structure .

Comment: Are you running all tests against Google Chrome when the failures happen?

Comment: Yes, i use only google chrome in these TCs.

Comment: @BenceKaulics I tried inserting the absolute paths but it still does not work. Do you have any other suggestions?